# can't grock simple sed backreference

Tags: php, regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed to use a backreference as a replacement.

```
echo MXN-PKG-0.3.6-62.noarch.rpm | sed -E 's/(\d\.\d\.\d+)/\1/'
```

Tested the regex on something I'm familiar with, [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match), and it looks solid

```
php > $str = 'MXN-PKG-0.3.6-62.noarch.rpm';
php > preg_match('/(\d\.\d\.\d+)/', $str, $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "0.3.6"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "0.3.6"
}
```

Where am I going wrong with sed? I'm using the extended regex and have looked at numerous sites showing examples of capturing the first backreference with `\1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed's regex engine (ERE) doesn't support `\d` for digits

Use this sed:

```
echo MXN-PKG-0.3.6-62.noarch.rpm | sed -E 's/([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+)/[\1]/'
MXN-PKG-[0.3.6]-62.noarch.rpm
```

On Linux:

```
echo MXN-PKG-0.3.6-62.noarch.rpm | sed -r 's/([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+)/[\1]/'
MXN-PKG-[0.3.6]-62.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Interesting, I'd thought that would come along with the extended regexp. Thanks. I'm probably confusing of PCRE with ERE, now that I think about it.

Comment: Yes that's right, none of other conventional Unix tool support `\d` except `grep -P` (which is PCRE)

Comment: Your example is still spitting out the full input string for me on both Linux and OSX. (Linux is what I care about tho).

Comment: Added OSX and Linux example and their outputs. (used square brackets for showing this example only)

Comment: Nice, I realized after your update I'd need additional backreferences to get only the piece I'm looking for in the output. Here's what I've settled on `sed -r 's/(.*:?)([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+)(.*)/\2/'`. Thanks again!